# How to convert PPTX to mp4 in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**I am using ruby 1.9.3 it would be helpful if i can get any gem name or method to convert the .ppt to .mp4

Comment: Are you really still using Ruby 1.9.3 and a Ruby on Rails 3.x version? Both are outdated for at least 5 years.

Comment: yes we are on track on latest one... but existing project is going on

Answer (score 0):

**PPTX >> PNG >> MP4**

You can use [docsplit](http://documentcloud.github.io/docsplit/) gem to convert PDF to PNG

```
Docsplit.extract_images('test.pdf', :format => [:png])
```

and [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) to convert PNGs to MP4.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i img_%d.png -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1280:-2 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

if your player cannot handle a non-standard frame rate add `-r 30` eg. VLC

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i img_%d.png -r 30 -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1280:-2 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

check [docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow) for more